# How to keep boolean 'true' even after a loop in 2D arrays in java

Tags: java, loops

i was doing my individual assignment and i encounter logic error.
My assignment was to make bus booking system. i got everything right except, if i want to buy another ticket, the booked seat will disappear. The boolean value keep returning to 'false' after the loop is done. this is fraction of my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class IndividualAssignment {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, IOException {
        int row, col, seatNumber;
        boolean seatingChart[][] = new boolean[10][3];
        String yesno;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        while (true) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    seatingChart[i][j] = false;
                }
            }
    
            // Print the seating chart
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    if (seatingChart[i][j]) {
                        System.out.print("X ");
                    } else {
                        System.out.print((i * 3 + j + 1) + "  ");
                    }
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            // Prompt the user to enter a seat number
            System.out.print("Enter a seat number: ");
            seatNumber = input.nextInt();
    
            // Calculate the row and column of the seat based on the seat number
            row = (seatNumber - 1) / 3;
            col = (seatNumber - 1) % 3;
    
            // Check if the seat is available
            if (!seatingChart[row][col]) {
                // If the seat is available, mark it as taken (true)
                seatingChart[row][col] = true;
                System.out.println("Seat " + seatNumber + "(row " + (row + 1) + ", column " + (col + 1) + ") has been reserved.");
            } else {
                // If the seat is not available, print an error message
                System.out.println("Sorry, that seat is already taken.");
            }
            // Print the seating chart
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    if (seatingChart[i][j]) {
                        System.out.print("X ");
                    } else {
                        System.out.print((i * 3 + j + 1) + "  ");
                    }
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
    
            System.out.println("Do you want to continue? (y/n)");
            yesno = input.next();
    
            if (yesno.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
                break;
            } else if (!yesno.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
                System.out.println("Invalid input. Please enter y or n.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**The result:**

```
1  2  3  
4  5  6  
7  8  9  
10  11  12  
13  14  15  
16  17  18  
19  20  21  
22  23  24  
25  26  27  
28  29  30  

Enter a seat number: 1
Seat 1(row 1, column 1) has been reserved.

X 2  3  
4  5  6  
7  8  9  
10  11  12  
13  14  15  
16  17  18  
19  20  21  
22  23  24  
25  26  27  
28  29  30  

Do you want to continue? (y/n)
y

1  2  3  
4  5  6  
7  8  9  
10  11  12  
13  14  15  
16  17  18  
19  20  21  
22  23  24  
25  26  27  
28  29  30  

Enter a seat number: 2
Seat 2(row 1, column 2) has been reserved.

1  X 3  
4  5  6  
7  8  9  
10  11  12  
13  14  15  
16  17  18  
19  20  21  
22  23  24  
25  26  27  
28  29  30  
Do you want to continue? (y/n)
```

I was expecting the selected seat to keep being 'true' even after I choose "y". I hope anyone can solve my problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Set the initial Seating Chart (where all elements are set to false) array above (outside) the `while` loop. Now it is directly under the `while (true) {` and upon every iteration, all array elements are reset to false.

Comment: thank you so much. Works like a charm. i don't even realize that. i don't really understand how array & boolean after all.

Comment: @DevilsHnd why don't you post an answer and husinyusoff can accept so this question can be closed

Comment: @Matthias - For the simple reason that questions in StackOverflow are never closed unless a **Closed** flag has been specifically issued by a User or Users with **close/reopen** votes privilege to do as such. You will find that most new Users to StackOverflow never accept an answer anyways....I have hundreds. And Above all, I don't need the reputation points. Some answers can just plainly be answered through a comment and these comments should be read by all readers of the post in any case. By doing so, it can be quickly determined that the situation has been solved.

Comment: by closed I mean accepted answer so that I don't find this question like I just did when I'm searching questions with no answer, I know too many people don't accept, but ideally it should be an accepted answer. Even unaccepted is better than nothing, I first look at the questions with no answer. But you do you